# IE 8 .png Problem

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, background, slideshow

Ok I have searched and found several issues on this but for some reason I can't find the solution to my problem I have the background color set and page background set with CSS (had to change image paths to typeimage because of a filter

```
#page-background
{
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('images/page_g.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  z-index: -1;

}
```

and a body background

```
body {
background:url(images/page_t.jpg) repeat #805B38;
font-size: 84%;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #000;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 1.5em;

}
```

My Slideshow php code is

```
<?php if ($mission) : ?><div id="slideshow-bottom">
<div id="mission"><?php print $mission; ?></div></div><?php endif; ?>
<div class="slideshow">
<img src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/Life.png" width="950" height="355" alt="slideshow 1"/>
<img src="<?php print $base_path . $directory; ?>/images/slideshows/Death.png" width="950" height="355" alt="slideshow 2"/>

</div>
</div>
```

Now the slide show PNG's work fine in Firefox and Chrome but IE 8 seems to be so transparent it shows the background color set in the CSS body tag instead of the background image.

What am I missing?

After some more research I have found that the problem is not the PNG's  and background its self It appears to be with the jquery slideshow because if I comment out all but one image the one image works perfect anyony have any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Can't you just omit the background color?

Comment: nope it shows white then

Comment: you are using `jpeg` and they are not transparent; probably you've saved your `png` images as `jpg`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year later but:

Your background shorthand is incorrect. The color should come first, before the URL.

`background: #805B38 url(images/page_t.jpg) repeat;`

See this resources for more CSS shorthand explanations by Dustin Diaz:
http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/